# Use Svelte Component as Slot

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I trying to build a new Svelte application.
So, I have the following `Main.svelte` file:

```
<script>
    import TitleSlide from '../lib/slides/TitleSlide.svelte'
</script>
<TitleSlide>
    <span slot="title">To infinity and beyond</span>
    <span slot="caption">or story about toys</span>
</TitleSlide>
```

File `TitleSlide.svelte` has 2 slots:

```
<section>
    <h1>
        <slot name="title">
            <span class="missing">Unknown title</span>
        </slot>
    </h1>
    <p class="fragment">
        <slot name="caption"></slot>
    </p>
</section>
```

It works great, next step I rewrite `Main.svelte` to this:

```
<script>
    import TitleSlide from '../lib/slides/TitleSlide.svelte'
    import Title from '../lib/partial/Title.svelte'
    import Caption from '../lib/partial/Caption.svelte'
</script>
<TitleSlide>
    <Title slot="title">To infinity and beyond</Title>
    <Caption slot="caption">or story about toys</Caption>
</TitleSlide>
```

And simple `Title.svelte` and `Caption.svelte`:

```
<slot>
    <span class="missing">Unknown title/caption</span>
</slot>
```

But it looks strange, I want to use more simplified syntax like this:

```
<script>
    import TitleSlide from '../lib/slides/TitleSlide.svelte'
    import Title from '../lib/partial/Title.svelte'
    import Caption from '../lib/partial/Caption.svelte'
</script>
<TitleSlide>
    <Title>To infinity and beyond</Title>
    <Caption>or story about toys</Caption>
</TitleSlide>
```

So in other words, I want to use Component as Slot, I want to create two Components `Title` and `Caption`, and set up a target slot for them.

I'm not sure if it is possible or not :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible right now. The only slot that can be assigned without naming it, is the `default` slot.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two default slots. So if you don't like using the somewhat clunking slot naming then I think you've only got two other options. First you can move everything into TitleSlide like this.

`Main.svelte` would just be:

```
<script>
    import TitleSlide from '../lib/slides/TitleSlide.svelte'
</script>
<TitleSlide />
```

and then your `TitleSlide.svelte` could be (you can obviously pass data into TitleSlide as props for reusing throughout your website, but I'm ignoring that for now):

```
<script>
    import Title from '../lib/partial/Title.svelte'
    import Caption from '../lib/partial/Caption.svelte'
</script>

<section>
    <h1>
        <Title>To infinity and beyond</Title>
    </h1>
    <p class="fragment">
        <Caption>or story about toys</Caption>
    </p>
</section>
```

Alternately you could do away with `TitleSlide` and then your `Main.svelte` becomes this:

```
<section>
    <Title>To infinity and beyond</Title>
    <Caption>or story about toys</Caption>
</section>
```

And then in your individual components you could add the markup that was in TitleSlide. It'd look like this in `Title.Svelte`

```
<h1>
    <slot>
        <span class="missing">Unknown title/caption</span>
    </slot>
</h1
```